# Android studio, LinearLayout "match parent - constant"

Tags: xml, android-studio

my question is :
how can i set a Linear layout height -> match parent -50 dp for exemple? i need my linear layout to let me some place under him to put a button

I dynamically generate buttons in a scroll view in this LinearLayout so i can't use

`<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">`

because the marginBottom  will push my button under the LinearLayout who "matchParent"

so can i do a matchParent -50 dp or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually try to put your linear layout inside a constraint layout, that gives you the ability to choose 50dp as a bottom margin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: okey well thank you for your answer but that not what i am looking for , if i set a marginBottom, my button who is under the LinearLayout will be pushed 50 dp under my LinearLayout

Comment: Well you could nest your button inside another constraint and solve the problem, but maybe I am just not getting what you need.